# Lightbox2 in Rails 6 is not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lightbox2

I tried to add lightbox2 to my rails project, but it does not work at all.

I followed the readme at [github](https://github.com/gavinkflam/lightbox2-rails)

In my application.css I added this:

```
 *= require lightbox
```

In my custom.css.scss i added this:

```
@import 'lightbox';
```

In installed jquery and in my javascript/packs/application.js i added this:

```
require('jquery')
require("lightbox")
```

In my show view i added this:

```
<table>
  <% @images.each do |image| %>
  <tr><td>
    <%= link_to image.img_url, data: { lightbox: @gallery.id } do %>
    <%= image_tag image.img_url %>
    <% end %>
    </tr><td>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

this is my application.html.erb file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PictureGallery</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I did put this in my initializers/assets.rb:

```
# Lightbox:
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( lightbox/* )
```

The view itself is working and the image URLs are working correctly. But if i click on an image, the image opens with its own image url which tells me, that lightbox is not working at all. It seems, the js is not loading.

What is wrong and how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i fixed it and it works. I copied the the content of the lightbox.js file from the github repository to a seperate file in javascript/packs/lightbox.js

After that i added `reguire("packs/lightbox")` to my application.js and finally i called the lightbox script in my application.html.erb like that:

```
<body>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'lightbox' %>
  </body>
```

Is there a problem in general in rails 6 for importing js that was installed somewhere by gems?

Answer (score 0):

config/initializers/assets.rb is no longer part of your app because you're using webpacker (javascript_pack_tag)